# Using a loop to prevent infinite IF statements

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
}`public static void drawBorder() {   // Asterisks based on wins
    if (gameCount.asterisk == 0) {
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    if (gameCount.asterisk == 1) {
        System.out.println("**********");
    }
    if (gameCount.asterisk == 2) {
        System.out.println("********************");
    }


}
```

How can I use a loop for this so it will print 10 asterisks multiplied by the value of gameCount.asterisk instead of using an unnecessary amount of if statements?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: MingShun's solution helped. All I needed was a for loop. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void drawBorder() {   // Asterisks based on wins
for (int i = 0; i < gameCount.asterisk; i++)
{
    System.out.print("**********");
}
}
```

Use print instead of println to print asterisks on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void drawBorder() {   // Asterisks based on wins
    StringBuilder asterisks = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < gameCount.asterisk; i++) {
        asterisks.append("**********");
    }
    System.out.println(asterisks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to generate the asterisks string:

```
String asterisks = "";
for(int i=0; i< gameCount.asterisk; i++)
{
    asterisks += "*";
}
```

However it would be more efficient to use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for this purpose:

```
String asteriskString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < gameCount.asterisk; i ++) {
    asteriskString.concat("**********");
}
System.out.println(asteriskString);
```

It adds 10 asterisks per gameCount.asterisk to the asteriskString. After that, you can print it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you could do it like this:

```
public static void drawBorder() {
    System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, gameCount.asterisk * 10)
                                .mapToObj(i -> "*")
                                .collect(Collectors.joining()));
}
```

`IntStream.range(0, gameCount.asterisk * 10)` will create a range, from `0` to `gameCount.asterisk * 10` (exclusive). For `gameCount.asterisk == 1` it would create:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then map each element in the range to `*` with `mapToObj(i -> "*")`:

```
["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]
```

And join the result into a `String` with `collect(Collectors.joining())`:

```
"**********"
```